# my discord.js code says it cant output an empty message even tho it shouldnt be empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js bot and I wanted to add an info command. I told it to get the user info and it spat this out in the console:

```
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15012) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\Počítač\da discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
```

And this is my code

```js
 function info(){
  message.channel.send(message.mentions.users);

  else if (command === "info"){
    if (!args[0]){
        return message.channel.send("You Need to provide an argument");
    }
    else if (message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.length === 0)){
        return message.channel.send("You Need to Ping someone!");
    }

    message.channel.send(info.username);
    message.channel.send(info.createdAt);
    message.channel.send(info.id);
    message.channel.send(info.joinedAt);
}



);
```

How can I 1. improve my code, 2. help fix the problem?

Comment: Your code seems to be a bit messed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just pretend I didn't see that `else if` going for a walk in your code block.

```
function info() {
  message.channel.send(message.mentions.users);

  if (command === "info") {
    if (!args) { // [0] is useless here
      return message.reply("You Need to provide an argument");
    } else if (!message.mentions.users) {
      return message.reply("You Need to Ping someone!");
    }

    message.channel.send(`${info.username}\n${info.createdAt}\n${info.id}\n${info.joinedAt}`)

  }
};
```

I'll add that I did not understand a thing about your code.
Here's what I changed:

- tried to correct SyntaxErrors
- remove redundant stuff
- did not send messages multiple times: it's because of ratelimits, and most importantly slowmodes

If that's the only code concerned by the error you gave, there's a high chance that yes, you're trying to send empty messages: where's that `info` even defined?